# Elastic Search: score as percentage

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to make a query for Elastic Search that returns a score as a percentage of the maximum score? Until now it returns a value like `"_score": 0.00786336,` and also a maximum score like `max_score": 0.13435546`, so I could try to convert my **result** but I want the result to be already in percentages, so I could use a minimum score, for example of 40 percent.

In short: Is there a way to get the _score in percentages of the max score, or is there another way of setting a minimum score? (seems to be hard because the max_score seems random)

Comment: Elasticsearch cannot do that for you out-of-the-box.

Comment: You can't know the range of scores that will be returned until you run the query.  So, you're looking at client-side conversion to do what you ask.

Answer (score 3):

`max_score` is not random, it's simply the `max` of all the scores of the result set from your query.

> [The `max_score` value is the highest `_score` of any document that matches our query.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/empty-search.html#_hits)

For example, if your `_score` values are: `[0.00786336, 0.0123, 0.0813523, 0.13435546]`, then your `max_score` is `0.13435546`.

There is also no limit to how high the `_score` may be based on the relevance of your matches (i.e. it can be in excess of `1`)

If you're trying to represent a "percentage match" using a ratio of `_score` from a hit to a `max_score`, you're going to get unreliable results, especially if you have a lot of low-score hits with little to no relevance, yet the `max_score` is close to those low scores.

If you're trying to filter out by a minimum score, you should use [`min_score`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-request-min-score.html)

Also see ["What is Relevance?"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relevance-intro.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already found min_score. This function makes no sense however, because it has to relate to the maximum score. I can not know in advance what the max_score is. For example, if I use a min_score of 1.2 and my max_score turns out to be 1.1, I have a problem. I need to know in advance what the scale/range of the _score is.

Comment: The score is the relevance - and the relevance is determined as a combination of "clues" as to whether the match is accurate or not. The more clues, the higher the score will be. If you use a percentage based on `_score / max_score` the percentage won't be accurate in any manner. If your strongest hit is a score of `1.1` and is actually a result you want, then you should never set `min_score` anywhere near that value. Even ES docs says it makes little to no sense to filter out scores, as the nature of ES only returns matches, simply sorted by relevance by default. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it can be to store the query hashes and the min_score (calculated as a percentage of max score). For example if the max_score is 1.1 the min_score can be 0.44 for that query which can help cut off irrelevant results.